# Convert decimal to binary in C

Tags: c, binary, decimal

I am trying to convert a decimal to binary such as 192 to 11000000. I just need some simple code to do this but the code I have so far doesn't work:

```
void dectobin(int value, char* output)
{
    int i;
    output[5] = '\0';
    for (i = 4; i >= 0; --i, value >>= 1)
    {
        output[i] = (value & 1) + '0';
    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: https://youtu.be/1MJ1o56x-g8 - this explains the whole solution of your problem.

Comment: There is no decimal here. `value` is already binary.

Answer (score 5):

The value is not decimal. All values in computer's memory are binary.

What you are trying to do is to convert int to a string using specific base.
There's a function for that, it's called `itoa`.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/

Comment: And function sprintf and sscanf

Comment: @holmium They don't usually support base-2. On the other hand, `itoa` is also non-standard (but far more common than `printf("%b"`

Comment: Decimal is another way to say a Base10 number. I believe the author is trying to say how do I convert a Base10 number to a Base2 number (regardless of internal representation).

Answer (score 3):

First of all `192`cannot be represented in `4` bits

`192 = 1100 0000` which required minimum `8` bits.

Here is a simple [C program to convert Decimal number system to Binary number system](http://codeforwin.org/2015/08/c-program-to-convert-from-decimal-to-binary-number-system.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <string.h>  

int main()  
{  
    long decimal, tempDecimal;  
    char binary[65];  
    int index = 0;  

    /* 
     * Reads decimal number from user 
     */  
    printf("Enter any decimal value : ");  
    scanf("%ld", &decimal);  

    /* Copies decimal value to temp variable */  
    tempDecimal = decimal;  

    while(tempDecimal!=0)  
    {  
        /* Finds decimal%2 and adds to the binary value */  
        binary[index] = (tempDecimal % 2) + '0';  

        tempDecimal /= 2;  
        index++;  
    }  
    binary[index] = '\0';  

    /* Reverse the binary value found */  
    strrev(binary);  

    printf("\nDecimal value = %ld\n", decimal);  
    printf("Binary value of decimal = %s", binary);  

    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: `strrev` is not part of C standard.

Answer (score 2):

5 digits are not enough for your example (192). Probably you should increase `output`

Answer (score 1):

A few days ago, I was searching for fast and **portable** way of doing `sprintf("%d", num)`. Found this implementation at the page [itoa with GCC](http://www.strudel.org.uk/itoa/):

```
/**
 * C++ version 0.4 char* style "itoa":
 * Written by Lukás Chmela
 * Released under GPLv3.

 */
char* itoa(int value, char* result, int base) {
    // check that the base if valid
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) { *result = '\0'; return result; }

    char* ptr = result, *ptr1 = result, tmp_char;
    int tmp_value;

    do {
        tmp_value = value;
        value /= base;
        *ptr++ = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [35 + (tmp_value - value * base)];
    } while ( value );

    // Apply negative sign
    if (tmp_value < 0) *ptr++ = '-';
    *ptr-- = '\0';
    while(ptr1 < ptr) {
        tmp_char = *ptr;
        *ptr--= *ptr1;
        *ptr1++ = tmp_char;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: wow, nice trick with palindromic array indexed from the middle.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this,  but be careful, you have to reverse the resulting string :-)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
char output[256]="";

int main()
{
int x= 192;
int n;
n = x;
int r;
do {
r = n % 2;
if (r == 1)
   strcat(output,"1");
else strcat(output,"0");
n = n / 2;
}
while (n > 0);

printf("%s\n",output);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So... did you check the output of your code to understand why it doesn't work?

```
So iteration 1 of your loop:
value = 192
i = 4
output[i] = (11000000 & 1) + '0' = 0 + 48 = 48 (char `0`)

Iteration 2 of your loop:
value = 96
i = 3
output[i] = (1100000 & 1) + '0' = 0 + 48 = 48 (char `0`)

Iteration 3 of your loop:
value = 48
i = 2
output[i] = (110000 & 1) + '0' = 0 + 48 = 48 (char `0`)

Iteration 4 of your loop:
value = 24
i = 1
output[i] = (11000 & 1) + '0' = 0 + 48 = 48 (char `0`)

Iteration 5 of your loop:
value = 12
i = 0
output[i] = (1100 & 1) + '0' = 0 + 48 = 48 (char `0`)

Final string: "00000"  and you wanted: "11000000"
```

See anything wrong with your code? Nope. Neither do I you just didn't go far enough. Change your output/loop to:

```
output[8] = '\0';
for (i = 7; i >= 0; --i, value >>= 1)
```

And then you'll have the correct result returned.

I would recomend just a more general approach, you're using a fixed length string, which limits you to binary numbers of a certian length. You might want to do something like:

```
loop while number dividing down is > 0
count number of times we loop
malloc an array the correct length and be returned
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void bin(int num) {
    int n = num;
    char *s = malloc(sizeof(int) * 8);
    int i, c = 0;
    printf("%d\n", num);

    for (i = sizeof(int) * 8 - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        n = num >> i;
        *(s + c) = (n & 1) ? '1' : '0';
        c++;
    }
    *(s + c) = NULL;
    printf("%s", s); // or you can also return the string s and then free it whenever needed
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bin(atoi(argv[1]));
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using while loop under a function also. I was just searching the solve for mine but the solves i get were not suitable, so I have done it accordingly the practical approach (divide using 2 until getting 0 and store the reminder in an array) and print the reverse of the array and [Shared Here](http://www.designprotrick.com/2013/08/c-programming-convert-decimal-number-to-binary.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main()
    {
        long long int a,c;
        int i=0,count=0;
        char bol[10000];
        scanf("%lld", &a);
        c = a;
        while(a!=0)
        {
            bol[i] = a%2;
            a = a / 2;
            count++;
            i++;
        }
        if(c==0)
        {
            printf("0");
        }
        else
        {
            for(i=count-1; i>=0; i--)
            {
                printf("%d", bol[i]);
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**Convert Decimal to Binary in *C Language***

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
    long int n,n1,m=1,rem,ans=0;
    printf("\nEnter Your Decimal No (between 0 to 1023) :: ");
    scanf("%ld",&n);

    n1=n;
    while(n>0)
    {
        rem=n%2;
        ans=(rem*m)+ans;
        n=n/2;
        m=m*10;
    }

    printf("\nYour Decimal No is   :: %ld",n1);
    printf("\nConvert into Binary No is :: %ld",ans);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

//C Program to convert Decimal to binary using Stack

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define max 100

int stack[max],top=-1,i,x;  


void push (int x)
{
  ++top;
  stack [top] = x;
}

int pop ()
{ 
   return stack[top];
}   


void  main()
{
  int num, total = 0,item;
  print f( "Please enter a decimal: ");
  scanf("%d",&num);
  while(num > 0)
  {  
    total = num % 2;
    push(total);
    num /= 2;
  }



 for(i=top;top>-1;top--)
 {     
     item = pop ();
     print f("%d",item);
 }

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

**This is the simplest way to do it**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int n,i,j,sum=0;
    printf("Enter a Decimal number to convert it to binary : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(i=n,j=1;i>=1;j*=10,i/=2)
        sum+=(i%2)*j;
    printf("\n%d",sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple program to convert a number from decimal to binary

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
void decToBinary(int);

int main()
{
    int number;

    printf("Enter number to convert to binary: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    
    decToBinary(number);
  return 0;
}

void decToBinary(int num)
{
    if (num == 0)
    {
        return ;
    }

    decToBinary(num / 2);
    printf("%d", num % 2);
}
```

Output of the Program:
[image: Output of the Program]

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps understanding the algorithm would allow you write or modify your own code to suit what you need.  I do see that you don't have enough char array length to display your binary value for 192 though (You need 8 digits of binary, but your code only gives 5 binary digits)

Here's a [page](http://www.cs.uaf.edu/~cs301/notes/Chapter3/node7.html) that clearly explains the algorithm.

I'm not a C/C++ programmer so here's my C# code contribution based on the algorithm example.

```
int I = 0;
int Q = 95;
string B = "";
while (Q != 0)
{
    Debug.Print(I.ToString());
    B += (Q%2);
    Q = Q/2;
    Debug.Print(Q.ToString());
    I++;
}

Debug.Print(B);
```

All the Debug.Print is just to show the output.

Comment: What's with all the down vote?  I did answer the question but not in C.  The algorithm is simple enough to implement in C on his own.

Answer (score -1):

```
//decimal to binary converter
long int dec2bin(unsigned int decimal_number){
  if (decimal_number == 0)
    return 0;
  else
    return ((decimal_number%2) + 10 * dec2bin(decimal_number/2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.  For instance, how do you address the overflow problem here?

Answer (score -1):

```
number=215
a=str(int(number//128>=1))+str(int(number%128>=64))+
str(int(((number%128)%64)>=32))+str(int((((number%12
8)%64)%32)>=16))+str(int(((((number%128)%64)%32)%16)>=8))
+str(int(((((((number%128)%64)%32)%16)%8)>=4)))
+str(int(((((((((number%128)%64)%32)%16)%8)%4)>=2))))
+str(int(((((((((((number%128)%64)%32)%16)%8)%4)%2)>=1)))))
print(a)
```

You can also use the 'if', 'else', statements to write this code.

Answer (score -2):

```
int main() 
{ 
 int n, c, k;
 printf("Enter an integer in decimal number system: ");
 scanf("%d", &n);
 printf("%d in binary number system is: ", n);
 for (c = n; c > 0; c = c/2) 
  {
   k = c % 2;//To
   k = (k > 0) ? printf("1") : printf("0");
  }
 getch();
 return 0; 
}
```